# Give me odd, even, square, cube, prime and composite 3-digit numbers

Tags: code-golf, integer, open-ended-function

Given a string which is guaranteed to be either `odd`, `even`, `square`, `cube`, `prime` or `composite`, your program or function must return an integer \$100\le N\le 999\$ which meets this description.

### Rules

- Your code must be deterministic.
- The choice of the integers is up to you. However, the six answers **must be distinct**. (For instance, if you return \$113\$ for *odd*, you cannot return \$113\$ for *prime*.)
- You may take the input string in full lower case (`odd`), full upper case (`ODD`) or title case (`Odd`) but it must be consistent.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

### Example

Below is an example of valid I/O:

- odd → \$501\$
- even → \$140\$
- square → \$961\$ (\$=31^2\$)
- cube → \$343\$ (\$=7^3\$)
- prime → \$113\$
- composite → \$999\$ (\$=37\times 3\times 3\times 3\$)

### Brownie points

For what it's worth, my own solution in JS is currently 24 bytes. So, brownie points for beating that.

**JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes**

```
MD5: 562703afc8428c7b0a2c271ee7c22aff
```

***Edit**: I can now unveil it since it was [found by tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230397/58563) (just with a different parameter name):*

> ```
> s=>parseInt(s,30)%65+204
> ```

Comment: I presume the string is not going to have the quotes around it?

Comment: At first, I thought this was simply 6 different-ish challenges wrapped into one, but the fact that it isn't a sequence and it can be any number in the range makes it a lot more interesting.

Comment: @pxeger I've removed the quotes in the description for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I don't often downvote things by Arnauld, but I don't like questions that are "let someone smart find a very short formula and then FGITW it in every language under the sun", and I *really* don't like them when said formula is found in 10 minutes

Comment: @pxeger tbf, he [was hoping it would take a little more time before someone came up with](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230373/give-me-odd-even-square-cube-prime-and-composite-3-digit-numbers#comment528420_230375) it.

Comment: @pxeger agreed, not going to downvote but not going to upvote either.

Comment: @pxeger I'm pretty sure other approaches may come out shorter in other languages, though.

Comment: Can input be taken as codepoints?

Comment: @xash I looked for a clear answer about that on meta, but didn't find one. Taking code points when you do have native strings seems a bit unfair, but I'd be interested in any insight from others about that.

Comment: is your 24 byte javascript answer using the same trick as the top javascript answer?

Comment: Too bad they need to be three digit numbers. Otherwise you could return (11,10,9,8,7,6).

Answer (score 26):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```python
lambda s:hash(s)%591^1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKiOxOEOjWFPV1NIwzvB/Wn6RQnl@UYpCZp5CtLq/i4u6joK6a5irH4gODgx1DHIFsZxDncB0QJCnL0TA3zfAP9gzxFU91opLQaGgKDOvREFdVdfQoFhB105BNUVdQVVBA2SyjkIamNbU/A8A)

Takes input in upper case and returns the following numbers:

```python
ODD        -> 263
EVEN       -> 554
SQUARE     -> 121
CUBE       -> 512
PRIME      -> 349
COMPOSITE  -> 371
```

Generated with this script which searches for formulas following `hash(s)%x?y`, where `?` is any binary operator:

```python
from sympy import primerange

# from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

hashes = [
    3275334880723988284, -8482906173967949472, -4710393751006474557,
    1654718638908055491, -6487253012923789248, 8925015453505786600
]

dyads = {
    int.__mul__, int.__mod__, int.__add__,
    int.__sub__, int.__rshift__, int.__lshift__,
    int.__xor__, int.__or__, int.__and__,
    int.__pow__, int.__floordiv__
}

primes = set(primerange(100, 1000))
squares = {x**2 for x in range(10, 32)}
cubes = {x**3 for x in range(5, 10)}

# for x in tqdm(range(6, 1000)):
for x in range(6, 1000):
    for y in range(1, 100):
        for z in dyads:
            a, b, c, d, e, f = r = [z(h%x, y) for h in hashes]
            if (
                len(set(r)) == 6
                and min(r) > 99
                and max(r) < 1000
                and a%2 == 1
                and b%2 == 0
                and c in squares
                and d in cubes
                and e in primes
                and f not in primes
            ):
                print(x, y, z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZPtbpswFIb/@yqONFWCyquMP7AdLbuRqUIkwEALmBqyhVS99sx2ykhT5h/AOc97jj9e009jbTp2uVTWtDBMbT9B0/bGjtDbpi1t3v0sEfoCgY8vRfvUmbHcGfNr1vkkQnU@1OUAW/iBwA1GpWCMK0UkZVopqjiGr4orqkmaSKZTqbnmkroslwlhmkmREJJyyYWQODRJUuGYSpnSRBEhuE6cPOVKUsFIQjVlUmnKFQb3EiQRXDBBhFRpSgh6RqiY8sIv6jX0a7rxKcva4yHL8ByYYgnywgc30uG4W6gd6qYal/gwxzcFJ2MXwe133t217s2fhVYHY2zR/M4y9IZQOHi/6qEco8WFyB0PBvcgcYyGl2Nug@j19PhIoTIWTq4bzFLsLIjf0P64@6di9yrh2zmRt3cm3s3oitN5tg26K5zJJmzIw@lm7gDf2czPngc3lrwfOYYdhj2GAkOJoXJLtf4SnaP64YRhikN17auvN@z5Q3lTQfQh4ceh7CJ/dDaOYbuF9JPAmQFt0zkBfAet13l@8vxb2OiqIn@gvn2yCndXuF6599t5d3BVUHhBsG4Vlx5fb8kqr8D9o//RxJtPJU7VjZE/bQzn@HL5Cw)

Answer (score 13):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
n=>121+'qvdou r'.search(n[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDsIgFEX3fgUbJSoJrg3d/IqmA8JDMZRHobAYvx1rnc45d7gvVVXWycXtEtBAs7IFOYqrONG1GiwkUZ5BJf3swyRm1oZuomgMPRMak1vgJxqXiNlt/yj3g3ktKh0GFQKducV0U/sPeCJH8u40howeuMdHb/eVsaH7sPYF)

### How?

I found six numbers which were close to 121, then simply placed them strategically.

And also thanks to Arnauld for reminding me of the `search` method.

Comment: TBH, I was hoping it would take a little more time before someone came up with that one. :-p Well done!

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks, when I saw the challenge, that somehow sprung into my mind. Took some time to find the right area to place the numbers, though.

Comment: BTW, you can use `search` instead of `indexOf`.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by removing 'q' and using 122.

Comment: @Kruga Thanks, but someone already posted an answer that does that, so I'll pass on that.

Answer (score 13):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

Takes in the input in full upper case. Sum of the character code points times 415 mod 998. A sum-less version would multiply the second element with 493, modulo 583.

```
ạ+×₄₁₅%₉₉₈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuhdqHpz9qannU1PioqVX1UVMnGHX8/6/kHOrkqvQ/AgA)

```
┌───┬────┬──────┬────┬─────┬─────────┐
│ODD│EVEN│SQUARE│CUBE│PRIME│COMPOSITE│
├───┼────┼──────┼────┼─────┼─────────┤
│403│580 │361   │343 │431  │339      │
└───┴────┴──────┴────┴─────┴─────────┘
```

Found with this crude J script, typing in the operations manually:

```
NB. returns 1 iff correct solution
test_f =: =@i.@# ([ -: *) [: (1 = 2&|)`(0 = 2&|)`((= <.)@%:)`(3 (= <.)@%: ])`(1&p:)`(1 < #@q:)`:0 [:(**/@~:)  (* <&1000 * >&99)"0
NB. try some variants
vars =: ,/ (a=:i.1000)|/ (b=:i.1000)*/ (1#.3&u:)&> ODD`EVEN`SQUARE`CUBE`PRIME`COMPOSITE
NB. show valid solutions
(((,/a,"0/b),.&<"1 [) #~ (test_f :: 0)"1) vars
```

Comment: Is taking it in uppercase allowed?

Comment: @rak1507 `You may take the input string in full lower case (odd), full upper case (ODD) or title case (Odd) but it must be consistent.`

Comment: Uh, but it sure looks like you're taking it as code points.

Comment: @Adám I was pretty sure, there was a meta-consensus for it, but I cannot find it. Well, I put in a bytecount equal Brachylog answer in. Not that it makes this answer/challenge more interesting, but alas …

Comment: I think separate languages should go into separate posts.

Comment: It might work in K too, for the same byte count.

Answer (score 8):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), <sup><s>21, 20</s></sup>  18 bytes

```
|Ig1n+8s%7[3g+5s]g
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7CIg1n%2B8s%257%5B3g%2B5s%5Dg&inputs=square)

This is my first ever answer with my own interpreter running on my own website!!!

## Outputs

```
odd: 113
even: 126
square: 121
cube: 125
prime: 127
composite: 119
```

## Explanation

```
|                 takes the user's input as a string
 I                splits this string into characters and stores them in consecutive memory 
                    slots
  g1              gets the character at index 1 (2nd character, Rattle is 0-indexed)
    n             converts this character to its ASCII code (int value)
     +8           adds 8 to this value
       s          saves this value to memory at the current pointer

   %7             takes mod(7) of the value on top of the stack. This gives three for
                    inputs of "prime" and "odd" (which are special cases)
     [3 .... ]    if the value on top of the stack is three, the code in this if statement 
                    executes
        g         gets the value from memory at the pointer
         +5       adds five to this value to fix the special cases
           s      saves the result to memory  
              g   gets the value saved in memory, prints implicitly
```

Comment: that color scheme is... interesting. glad you got it working though, and +1 :P

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>22</s></sup> 21 bytes

```python
lambda x:628*x[2]%831
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCyszIQqsi2ihW1cLY8H9afpFCsUJmnkKSur@Li4JrmKufQnBgqGOQq4JzqJOrQkCQpy@Q6e8b4B/sGeKqrldckJNZoqFpxaUABAVFmXklGsV6KanJ@SmpGpo6Ckq2dko6CmkaxZqa/wE)

Takes input in uppercase as a byte string. Takes the penultimate character's code, and applies some hashing to get:

```python
ODD => 323
EVEN => 120
SQUARE => 196
CUBE => 729
PRIME => 139
COMPOSITE => 158
```

Found using this brute-force program:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZVLbxoxFEb3/AqLKhJU02rGbyOxaBMWWaSkoemGsiAwKSOFRxho1SB@O51jCFHVR6RmFleee@3j77PvwOLHajKfqd3u8ur8otMTbbHJ0iwRWaoIjhCqkPEqeVVUVRxR0ARDzpCzzLOMHCNH1VMNMZALVENVkFmVk1IRHIGc4hWy1FRNDFQhS0vBkXPkIEtPAbJCrgKqkKsyXpGrkKt0DBVAGaqGEUoVShVKFSjlGSFScxAa@zojSF5VDIpATjMCqhGpLVWUasgaqPaMsK8xbThYA9TAM9g3WDXoM1AMAINVg1WDVQPF4NJAsUiz@LVYtVkcUUCf1TFQAGrxa/Fr0Wfxa4Fa/FqkuTSGaoqD4rgPh0uHSwfKcRUOfQ6KQ58D5ZDmODAPwHMBXsagCBS4Wg/Ko8VD8QjyWPVo8dylR5CHF/AWQAUEBQCBawx4C9gKoALnHDimACUACDgKwW1rvY/X7672XS2NhZrSspprTTl8PHhNE3E6ztK88VrjubPCxr6tRkpW8zwFFxtVGr6NlAvWdBInK822dnr9/vAdMUNmLOX8TCbj0m2tdjtfip4oZqJfE9VzUx@tb3JR3q@Hy1wslsU0F6P5dDEvi1Uu5uOxyL/ls/rbcnFXrBrN5LCIjcTeoYhfrzjtXlx2e@efOqJ7diY6nzsffl/ETr39Tpdxp9PjTt1qp86vOw1acR2CiyiYDy4Rb@SgJcQrsZrkVXacj/JSfJ8Uo0mlfj5ej3KxnhX361x8G96t8zIyePCZHIwme6fJk9UEr0k0W51f/6FfDOLOD@zcGxwp5Epyy@Hsa96Iv1Zp2mwdJzxOmj436fEpbsWXPxZ4GqV4HW/hREybVZD/mDucjZ8jRXtHVLst0v/mgYutc7K3um@9l9AOPXjgPX4@LyHu2/kAPPzJvMjvsV1hzuarJ27rrwt5KiGzVeO2XrQ3xVaU7U25FdP2ZroVo2GZtze9fjrY1pu73U8)

PS: I retract my downvote. Writing and optimising various brute-force programs was actually quite fun. (I don't think it's great to have too many challenges like this, though)

Comment: +1 but are we allowed to accept a `bytearray` when the specification is a "string in full lower case (`odd`), full upper case (`ODD`) or title case (`Odd`)"? (If so I have 21.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan what's your 21? Does it use a different hash? If not, I'm struggling to see how this can be shorter. And I'm not completely sure what you mean by "but are we allowed to accept a bytearray" - do you mean that you think mine is invalid (it accepts `bytes` not `bytearray`, and `bytes` is allowed by consensus), or do you mean that accepting `bytearray` instead of `bytes` allows a -1 golf (what?)?

Comment: Sorry `bytes` (`bytearray` is a function to go from `str` to `bytes`). Yeah, a different hash - it's in [my Python 2 post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230389/53748). Where is the consensus, since people are asking about character codes too?

Comment: @JonathanAllan [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8964) (at +11/-4 I think it meets our definition of consensus), but regardless they're [definitely generally accepted as an alternative for string input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22python+3%22+%22byte+string%22)

Comment: @JonathanAllan By the way, `bytearray` is a distinct type of its own, basically a mutable version of `bytes`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [the default.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36445/the-default) (looked for shorter salt/domain combinations with domains other than the one byte `1000` I'd considered and the different case formats allowed in the OP.)

```
91,651ḥ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters that yields an integer:

```
input      output   (notes)
odd        897
even       516
square     625      (25²)
cube       125      (5³)
prime      347
composite  752      (2⁴×47)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDix7u6H24o@tRw0ydE9sf7lj6/3D7o6Y1//9Hq@enpKjrKKinlqXmgejiwtLEolQQK7k0CUwXFGXmQgTycwvyizNLUtVjAQ)**

#### How?

```
91,651ḥ - Link: list of characters, S
  ,   ḥ - hash (S) using...
91      - ... salt: literal = 91
   651  - ... domain: literal 651 (i.e. a domain of [1..651])
```

The salt for the 8 byte version, using a domain of `[1..1000]` and only the lower-case version of the inputs, was found using this Python code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTbjpswEH33V4yQKtlZNgICJF0p@yNRhMhigrVgUtukjap@e@oLyy0Pq/gFPHPOmStcbqpq@eZ@Z82lFQqqXFY1OyFUirYBeWsuN@hdTF4EayhCqKAlNDnjmLwh0KctCgl7kFRhkfMzxWEQ@hAGQeBDRIjF0CvlS1CwBNkAXyhn@mh1dMnUwly2AjgwDgutPiNzWPmVMuYT8xhnnReFdg0eWks6x43Bp1j5q8uFzecvh9UKosdsfNhE5J8roDtNsJslNtF5hz30mtedxR483VLPB890zTxdSPNm5MzTlmANXzl6RytStGY0WU35WVVay3TFNTcXyooPJR5mxTKu1mbq2emmC8Yznzn9aqxllX/SLEpSLOhF4JpJha@ErCn/aAuKvU6VrztPGwp2ptqXhBE5MHgDBi@wO/oPwl7NlKp1MTMPmd1M19jYNd1gLevDbkQd0RR7NVjXTzR6ZV4r0xJ7@V2xmkI4W5h51VXJse2ab5n@vLd6xsREsQOe8XJefMuNLLdfpafZsWW7NX6anLi0h91@WiC0AvaLfpobWK75YwzUx4@TK2xH9apDzXwnQfPPwWIxL2ae7p/0XWy7DxnjBf3TxxRUdYJPxi67Zr4D2GXy/g6M6HzGm17mkBBYue/qMNE@HthxubBpPBYyvv2AcBfH6TaOg@1mG/xMkjAN08G9mhcw2HX4NEZOCiG9tlnG84ZmGez34GWZ5WSeK9H9qNH9/h8)); it can easily be modified to search other domains and to go through the three allowed case formats:

```python
import hashlib

from sympy import isprime


def main():
    odds = set(range(101, 1000, 2))
    evens = set(range(100, 1000, 2))
    primes = set()
    composites = set()
    for n in range(100, 1000):
        if isprime(n):
            primes.add(n)
        else:
            composites.add(n)
    squares = {n ** 2 for n in range(10, 32)}
    cubes = {n ** 3 for n in range(5, 11)}
    values = ["odd", "even", "square", "cube", "prime", "composite"]
    domain_length = 1000
    parts = [
        [
            int.from_bytes(
                hashlib.shake_256(repr(list(v)).encode("utf-8")).digest(512)[i : i + 8],
                "little",
            )
            for i in range(0, 512, 8)
        ]
        for v in values
    ]
    salt = 1
    while 1:
        if (
            hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, 3) in cubes
            and hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, 2) in squares
            and hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, 4) in primes
            and hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, 5) in composites
            and hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, 1) in evens
            and hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, 0) in odds
        ):
            print(salt - 1)
            break
        salt += 1


def hfn(parts, salt, domain_length, value_index):
    return (
        sum(
            ((salt >> i) - (salt >> i + 1)) * parts[value_index][i] for i in range(64)
        )
        % 18446744073709551616
        * domain_length
        >> 64
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How do you find these hash-based solutions? I've got a brute forcer running atm that's been going for close to 3 hours now with nothing

Comment: Added the code I wrote for this one.

Comment: 7 bytes: `91,651ḥ`, if you use title case (`Odd`, `Even`, ...)

Comment: Thanks @thedefault. I had not actually noticed the case optionality, and had not got around to searching domains other than the one-byte ones `1000` and `256`. I was also thinking using the input string itself as the salt might work (since if the first element is a string it's treated as a base-250 literal) with either a fixed object to hash (i.e. something like `,Ø°ḥ6`) but not tried a search.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 28 bytes

```javascript
n=>122+'vdou r'.search(n[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDsIgFEV3voKNEpWkXRu6@RVNB4SHYigPobAYvx1rnc45d7hPVVXWycXtEtBAs7IFOfXDcGLVYKGJiQwq6UcX5n7hbSQzQ2PYmbKY3Ao/0bhGzG77R7kdzK@i0mFQIbBFWExXtf@Ap3Kib6IxZPQgPN47u6@cj@TD2xc)

All credits go to Recursive Co., I would have commented but since It's my first time on posting on stackexchange I don't have the reputation for that.
When search doesn't find anything it return -1, making it possible to remove q and saving one byte.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

```javascript
x=>parseInt(x,30)%17^212
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNdb5swFH3nVxxVSWu3HiJEy7Sl9CXKw54SKcpT1SgEzGaUGIYh7Rbx2zODR@pGSENC3I9zry/nXKfhMVRRIfLyk8xifk6C81vwlIeF4t9lSd7Y2KPD0ZeNP/LPUSZVtufuPvtBEnKTxfENpVPnKsyPXPbF1a8qLHhfJqp2vfG8EIf@guyQZ0qUJuksAslfseIl0d7cdla2s7adpe3MbCfJChCBACPPm0LgsTEa6@GB4uQAImnyQ/gINIhi4YZxTIQuvcp5FPNLrrYbm75j3@q6Mkjc4wr9uRvCAq878D3GLTqPvuG/g7eAVAP0ualOC/3pcu@jp/9GN1FgZv1e82gtSiErjjwyodox79L6V@cY7kWsj0oqGZUikyCyOux4oUzjgpdVIfG8YJgzrBjWDEuG2Yur16f4TUjCNA8InpC4P0PVFT@LF0pxe9ue22nWNXaV@MP18AEmegS9F69ZESs9w1ZvKkOzlwxmCxmanWNoN0w73T5tXZXvRUnuGO6oYzTYhYo3nH2dojUfA4wnxv5ArDDE9vBuMT/yJoZ7v4VY9BsBWtpIO7h7CHMSNRRcbmPE2mOpVklgg5TS9@pWmMsl2X68xINTU1fT4eAk6s3glNZ0exG0tlSsnfNf)

Some other 24 bytes

```javascript
x=>parseInt(x,30)%65+204
x=>parseInt(x,33)%37+497
x=>parseInt(x+87,35)%349
```

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
x=>Buffer(x)[3]%29^115
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPbbuIwEH3PVxxV0NqtN@KiVtpt04dFPIOEeEIg0sTZdQRJ1klod1G@nU7ihroo0iJFzOXMeHzmOPYPfh5olRXfkjSUp8g7vXnPP8sokpq98dV43R993wyH96cgTfJ0J91d@otF7CoNwyvOH52LsDzIpCue/yl9LbsyQfnSGc@02ncXpPsszVVhks7MS@QrFrJg5E1tZ2E7S9uZ287EdqJUgyl4GA4Gj1B4qo3aurvjODqAiup8HyN4BOKYuX4YMkWlF7kBx/Scq@zGpu94ZHVdGCRucYG@b4ewwMsWfItxg86CH/jv4A0gJgCdG1Na0V@b@xw9/hjdRIGJdb36R7soVFJKZIEJVY755tZdnYO/UyEdFZVJUKg0AUvK/YvUuWmsZVHqBKuZwFRgIbAUmAtM1i7JR/9lLBLEA7xnRO5vP2@LV2rNOa6vm3PbnbWN3Vz9kzS8hwcagXTxmuowpxm2pFSBWpcCRoUCteYEGoWR0@pp6@bZThXsRuCGO2YHlDGU1caTh3FjfeFUGUAH5Rbpw8GDoX3UQCzmDfcNY6yZ2d37GQvq2388w4Cv6Mw1bUdhg5jzz9JmIefHsf3ydHtHqqrW/d5RVZveMa625y1W1uoq5/QO)

Some other 22 bytes

```javascript
x=>Buffer(x)[3]%87^115
x=>Buffer(x)[3]%89^113
x=>Buffer(x)[3]%55^115 // UpperCase
x=>Buffer(x)[3]%57^113 // UpperCase
```

Comment: I have no idea how this would work, but is there anything you can do with `s.search\`e\``?

Comment: @Ausername hadn't find some useful formula using it. Tried both title case and lower case. Not sure why...

Comment: really interesting answers. Can you explain how you found them/the program you used for bruteforcing

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 22 bytes

```java
s->150-s.hashCode()%30
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Ba8MwDIXv@RXCEHCGY1LGLutWKIOdtlN3Gzu4sZM6TWzPkgNl9LdnbrsdhPTQ09M3qFnVgz4udgo@EgxZy0R2lF1yLVnv5N26aEeFCO/KOvgpAELaj7YFJEW5zd5qmPKO7yha139@gYo9VlcrwId/865//Ut7unk20MHzgvVm9dDUKA8KDy9eG16V982yvt51PgKfVQR8BOa1FmY2TuB3UtGINu2NCNFOefSZHC0ZJjGMljgTrPp/DrA7IZlJ@kQy@x11nJWrJmeWunRMAAropAphPG3xAsqxqm4A5@JS5@UX)

### Outputs

```java
       odd: 139
      even: 140
    square: 169
      cube: 125
     prime: 149
 composite: 155
```

### Alternate

```java
s->160-s.hashCode()%50
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Ba8MwDIXv@RXCEHCGY9LDdli3QhnstJ2629jBjZ3UaWJ7lhwoo789c9vtIKSHnp6@Qc2qHvRxsVPwkWDIWiayo@ySa8l6J@/WRTsqRHhX1sFPARDSfrQtICnKbfZWw5R3fEfRuv7zC1TssbpaAT78m3f961/a082zgQ6eF6w3q4emRnlQeHjx2vCqvG@W9fWu8xH4rCLgIzCvtTCzcQK/k4pGtGlvRIh2yqPP5GjJMIlhtMSZYNX/c4DdCclM0ieS2e@o46xcNTmz1KVjAlBAJ1UI42mLF1COVXUDOBeXOi@/)

### How

Brute-forced with this code:

```java
import java.util.*;

class Main {

  private static long[] cubes = computeCubes(100, 1000);
  private static long[] squares = computeSquares(100, 1000);
  private static long[] primes = computePrimes(100, 1000);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int o = 0; o <= 1000; o++) {
      for (int m = 2; m < 10000; m++) {
        if (test(o, m)) {
          System.out.printf("o = %d, m = %d%n", o, m);

          System.out.printf("odd: %d%n",       f("odd",       o, m));
          System.out.printf("even: %d%n",      f("even",      o, m));
          System.out.printf("square: %d%n",    f("square",    o, m));
          System.out.printf("cube: %d%n",      f("cube",      o, m));
          System.out.printf("prime: %d%n",     f("prime",     o, m));
          System.out.printf("composite: %d%n", f("composite", o, m));
          System.out.printf("%n");
        }
      }
    }
  }

//  static long f(String s, int o, int m) {
//    return o + s.hashCode() % m;
//  }

  static long f(String s, int o, int m) {
    return o - s.hashCode() % m;
  }

  static boolean test(int o, int m) {
    var odd =       f("odd",       o, m);
    var even =      f("even",      o, m);
    var square =    f("square",    o, m);
    var cube =      f("cube",      o, m);
    var prime =     f("prime",     o, m);
    var composite = f("composite", o, m);

    var values = new long[]{ odd, even, square, cube, prime, composite };
    
    var result = Arrays.stream(values)
                   .filter(v -> 100 <= v && v < 1000)
                   .distinct()
                   .count()
                 == 6;
    
    result &= odd % 2 == 1;
    result &= even % 2 == 0;
    result &= Arrays.binarySearch(squares, square) >= 0;
    result &= Arrays.binarySearch(cubes, cube) >= 0;
    result &= Arrays.binarySearch(primes, prime) >= 0;
    result &= Arrays.binarySearch(primes, composite) < 0;

    return result;
  }

  private static long[] computeSquares(int min, int max) {
    var minSqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(min); if (minSqrt * minSqrt < min) minSqrt++;
    var maxSqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(max);
    var squares = new long[maxSqrt - minSqrt + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      var sqrt = minSqrt + i;
      squares[i] = sqrt * sqrt;
    }
    return squares;
  }
  private static long[] computeCubes(int min, int max) {
    int minCbrt = (int)Math.pow(min, 1/3d); if (minCbrt * minCbrt * minCbrt < min) minCbrt++;
    int maxCbrt = (int)Math.pow(max, 1/3d);
    var cubes = new long[maxCbrt - minCbrt + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
      int cbrt = minCbrt + i;
      cubes[i] = cbrt * cbrt * cbrt;
    }
    return cubes;
  }
  private static long[] computePrimes(int min, int max) {
    var composites = new boolean[max];
    composites[2] = false;
    var primes = new long[max];
    var primeCount = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < max; i++) {
      if (!composites[i]) {
        for (int c = i * i; c < max; c += i) {
          composites[c] = true;
        }
        primes[primeCount++] = i;
      }
    }
    var minPos = Arrays.binarySearch(primes, 0, primeCount, min);
    var maxPos = Arrays.binarySearch(primes, 0, primeCount, max);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(primes, minPos < 0 ? ~minPos : minPos, primeCount);
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZNb9swDL3nV3ADUti146YdsMPcbBh6HjYsxyIHxVYadf7IJDlbMWR/vaM@LMuuk6U5xBb1@ERST5QfyZ7MHvMfz8@s3NVcwiMakkayIrlMJ5OsIELAF8Iq@DOZAOw42xNJQUgiWQZFXT3cryBr1lTAArK63DWS3qlhcD2fx4B/8zA96ih@NoT7rktjOMsZraXv@02Pe67Kt1kX6GNd9zXLocR0gqXkTNMQ/iBCzA7wt6k5BKySUCPtPMXH7UJz4WsUtSgPVyLuJsXHrYYhrvRxAGwDgaRCBnUMZejPACyfhKRlUjcywVwquQneqnWneax5p/m0ehuDdtSpnPLL8w@tgw1RG93QLJ@eZqF7WvVprLEdnsViNtXncUYzPItFaepFLMr4qli0Rno0rdEOz4sFBVYLJjsm39ju0f9Y0NGDHCb@U/0fJpOrK/BFjssYmYKIQcvSPEqlI4UF4FQ2vEKhRiCSLRHbuzqnQQhTKFMNOSjlnMvZY5yNMPb51nVdUFKBFvgY155wQBWimI@LMnVIpbQWOia8DmnUZLBj4uqQSjEe5wsBdUitCgsdE4nH2e48oseEYA@rgu5J0egeVdFftm/9URWJdbKxTSTWYcYmhNjjP5hFHR22xqaQSPeZc/IkEiE5JWVgVgk9@blfsmGFpDzYw@yjalGqoe3h4gL/TMsa98qZkKzKZDA@ndVNNTq3WMB7L2Yb78VCq2AKNwpwnQ7m9L7byflw0ma6ZhXhT0tKeLYN7LXRli@Ej2c66ovKVPt8J3PP2N15vZvbzRArPrfasIfMMLhjdeR27V@N@oCxyp408ts/a2hf/uRKIAoWfiFymwg0BDgRpvoyaiGXDnyr3sJ2GEWd0JH9CB0uOzyNPZW3njO3SgTXq7R/yTJzyTKMwFIkBa0e5BZt/i1q1tBxdGysbaXW9Z6tcF6Y1NQjnXTt1ZbbQk29/1Nu8xFzrNjWfrceVGdX/wo0/vrqXd5VXOMu4eVbV3s1bGtvFxtnJ79b9l6TG5ZfO8/cQqfLrwnGi6@Q2botvuVyxdeOpvSZycx7jOyAxp9Vf/s1d0rt7mS1udv7SKVvk@0g9zcqyA0pBB30/GHlVoP5O9XswJ36Xv1uTP3Qa1g23Pg33ups5X/7OY4MORiWi6X4ankyiNDY/1T0mDKVh@QNffktATah@y7uKFJwt18Hb0tsw/hWCzjdweaxV4hYK7bXI17P4NqHlYX1zerd09fNd1I9UOdqI8TWCZ/grx19sGafNjSyOjw//wM)

Comment: Which Java version is that using? The exact formula used by `String.hashCode()` changed between versions, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @PaüloEbermann looking as far as Java 1.0, `String.hashCode()` hasn't changed, ever. You must be mistaken with another method or class.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(s[:-1])-2+6*(81in s)+(77in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbLCoJAFADQfV9xceOdfIAFGYJB5SxcmOajTbXQxiHBF15b9PWTdFZn/M7vod8q6T9UW3aVKIE8@nRId89ynszaGLs17p2mB2IGuu4/Sg4TECyv9DgIgN/4BbJrcUw5nIsThyQNo6VxlMRZmHPdprFtZmTeChbj1PQzki3q1yBqZCZo/kEzQSIxpn4)

Takes input as `bytes` in uppercase.

Not as short as an [uninteresting clone of the current shortest formula](https://tio.run/##DclBCsMgFEXReVfxcBKlIWA7C6QbaTswVakQ/cavga7e5o4O3PyrX0r37pdX30xcrQHP@qavYj8sNRQx@ZCs5Kd@q@6pgBESBrIW7nAJvDdTHD5tdcglxJMUM3Gobpg4b6FKNV9wdt5UJY8Qy0OM8JKV6n8), and can very likely be golfed further, but I wanted to show a different approach.

My first instinct on seeing this challenge was to use `sum`, because you can sum a byte string in Python 3 and it's a useful quick method to do string lookups like this.

Cube numbers were definitely the hardest to get to behave with a sum, because there are only 3 practicable cube numbers in the region of the sums of the strings (\$ 6^3, 7^3, 8^3 \$).

I played around with different slices of the string and different input casings, and I found that `sum(s[:-1])` was promising:

```python
ODD => 147
EVEN => 224
SQUARE => 396
CUBE => 218
PRIME => 312
COMPOSITE => 622
```

Subtracting 2 makes `216`, a cube, while keeping the rest. `396` is also very close to `400`, and the rest were pretty easy too.

`81in s` tests for a `Q`, and then `+6*()` adds 6 if there is one (abusing Python's weak interpretation of booleans). Similarly, `+(77in s)` fixes `PRIME` by making `311` instead of `310`. (I'm sure these bits can be golfed somehow.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>26</s></sup> 25 bytes

```python
lambda x:497+int(x,33)%37
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCsMgFAX3PcUjUKJUurEQGkhP0o2pSoXot35T0tNbZzUwMPlX35R088uzbSau1uCYb/fpElIVh9JanvXUPBUwQsJI1sJ9XQJ/dlMcXvvqkEuIXSlm4lDdeOW8hSrkfEKn1/5ihWF5DApesJTtDw)

*-1 thanks to ovs*

Converts the string to an integer in base 33, then does a bit of hashing.

Outputs:

```python
odd => 509
even => 508
square => 529
cube => 512
prime => 499
composite => 522
```

Found using this brute-force script and a tiny bit of manual filtration:

```python
PRIMES = {101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997}
SQUARES = {256, 900, 144, 400, 529, 784, 289, 676, 169, 441, 576, 961, 196, 324, 841, 729, 225, 100, 484, 361, 625}
CUBES = {125, 216, 343, 512, 729}

CUBE, SQUARE, PRIME, EVEN, ODD, COMPOSITE = "cube", "square", "prime", "even", "odd", "composite"

for s in range(800):
    for b in range(32, 37):
        for m in range(1, 10000):
                if \
                    s + int(CUBE, b) % m in CUBES \
                    and \
                    s + int(SQUARE, b) % m in SQUARES \
                    and \
                    s + int(PRIME, b) % m in PRIMES \
                    and \
                    s + int(COMPOSITE, b) % m not in PRIMES \
                    and \
                    (s + int(ODD, b) % m) % 2 \
                    and \
                    (s + int(EVEN, b) % m) % 2 == 0:
                        print(f"{s} + int(x, {b}) % {m}")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZRNb9pAEIbv/hUrpEqg@mDv90bi0CYcckhJQ9JTLxCg5YBNgVStkH873WfNR6RGqkR9GMY7u4/ed2bN6vf2e12p/f7@4fZuMBJ9sSuLMhdloQiOEGIoeZW8KqoqZRQ0wbBmWLPss2SOzFH1VEMKrAWqIRZkGdekVARHYE3xCllqqiYFqpClpeBYc6xBlp4CZIVcBVQhV5W8IlchV@kUIkAZqoYMpQqlCqUKlPJkiNQ0QmNflwTJq0pBEVjTZEA1IrWlilINWQPVngz7GtOGxhqgBp7BvsGqQZ@BYgAYrBqsGqwaKAaXBopFmsWvxaotU0YBfVanQAGoxa/Fr0Wfxa8FavFrkeaKFOIWB8UxD4dLh0sHyjEKhz4HxaHPgXJIczTMA/AMwMsUFIECo/WgPFo8FI8gj1WPFs8sPYI8vIC3ACogKAAIjDHgLWArgAr0OdCmACUACDgKwTXZ6PPTh4f2VktjoRZcWc1YC5qPB6@5RHTHWS5vGmvqOydsurcxUzLu8xRcuqjS8G0UDFhzk@isNE12/fTx8B2xQ5YcpX@mlOlok6UtuWjF5SJ9ebkYfBl8ysXw5iYX18O7@@Ho9nEQMZ3nl8msk4vO5sfLeJ2y1XqxTMns56zit55O@Xmul6t6s9jOOlk2r9diIxaVWI@rb7OuL4reVSbiQ2FyLijJ3T/UjvXluZ7@CorT6dfPYi6@/rXIsxHvI2DbbW1OeuJdS2w78/aZcTX9B@3YrjPvON1LiYfGn4GH/8BLeaexnZhVvf0PbvcITpeiRRLk5aT2kr1G9fuiuHrzEE@8avHUvLPbNAfCr1zsJg1nd8um09vv/wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda s:hash(s)%853^702
```

An unnamed function accepting a string that returns an integer:

```python
      odd: 783
     even: 832
   square: 196
     cube: 512
    prime: 661
composite: 679
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3NCsIwEITvPsVeJAkUEYuoAX0SEVKTkoD5aXYriPTZY1Ln8g0zMJM@ZGM4lPF6Ly/lB60ApVVoOYrt@dg/TvtaxgxkkMAF4CxqzTpg5m1CI06zyqa55zysTNn5fxB9iujIMCE3UFWbQMC@8nZZJFT0C9vVda@It4MOxpVClB8)**

---

...or perhaps 21 in Python 3?

```python
lambda b:b[2]**95%547
```

where `b` is `bytes` if that is allowed in place of a string.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
HƵ₅%₁+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a9cVmlokGWvpKBrp6BkX/nf49jWR02tqo@aGrX/6/zPT0lRSC1LzVMoLixNLEpVSC5NSlUoKMrMBTLzcwvyizNLUgE)

This computes `from_hex(input)%193+256`, found by the same script I used for my Python answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｉ﹪⁺⁴⁷⁰⍘Ｓγ⁸⁶⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzc/pTQnXyMgp7RYw8TcQEfBKbE4NbgEqCBdwzOvoLQEytbUUUjXBBIWZmaamprW//8XFGXmpv7XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in lower case. Explanation:

```
       Ｓ        Input string
      ⍘ γ       Converted from base 95
  ⁺⁴⁷⁰          Plus 470
 ﹪       ⁸⁶⁶    Modulo 866
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

These constants were the only ones I could find that worked with lowercase inputs. There are other constants that work for title or upper case:

```
           lower    Title       UPPER
           + 470 162 710 100 254 588 708
           % 866 586 778 840 851 948 972
         odd 327 155 401 723 683 671 659
        even 206 400 750 278 286 386 470
      square 729 169 529 529 361 841 841
        cube 343 343 729 729 343 729 729
       prime 269 397 457 659 467 919 571
   composite 299 511 119 539 495 451 763
```

I also tried base 26 but I didn't find any solutions. I also tried "base 1000" which had one solution for each case: `+499, %837: 819 176 121 512 389 371` (lowercase) `+674, %703: 173 194 225 216 577 512` (title case) `+334, %667: 353 186 625 512 383 372` (upper case).

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 74 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/aeven=120,square=121,odd=123,cube=125,prime=127,composite=128,%1
```

Case insensitive. Explanation: Sets six variables and evaluates the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
Hash@#~Mod~619-90&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yOxOMNBuc43P6XOzNBS19JA7X9AUWZeSbSyrl1atHJsrIKagr6DQrVSfkqKko6CUmpZah6ILi4sTSxKBbGSS5PAdEFRZi5EID@3IL84syRVqfY/AA)

```
Hash@#~Mod~775+35&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yOxOMNBuc43P6XO3NxU29hU7X9AUWZeSbSyrl1atHJsrIKagr6DQrWSf0qKko6CkmtZah6IDi4sTSxKBbGcS5PANFBbLkQgP7cgvzizJFWp9j8A)

This code was developed on Mathematica `12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)` and verified on `12.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 16, 2019)`. According to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html),

> The "Expression" hash code is computed from the internal representation of an expression and may vary between computer systems and from one version of the Wolfram Language to another.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 23 bytes

```c
#define f(n)n[3]%29^115
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU0jTzMv2jhW1cgyztDQ9H9uYmaehmY1l0JBUWZeSZqChpJqSkyekk6ahlJ@SoqSpqY1TApJJrUsNQ@HVHFhaWJRKrIkspHJpUmpODQCBXJxySXn5xbkF2eWQORr/wMA)

- just a port of [tsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230397/84844)  the difference is : while js had to use buffer() C can access every single character directly.